# How to fix gulp inject files

Tags: html, css, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-inject

**Hello**

I would like to ask how it is possible to make it work inject files on my localhost .
Maybe i have something wrong in **gulpfile.js**
I tried to fix it but it does not work
**CSS & JS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title></title>
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/min/all-min.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
</head>


<body>

<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="/assets/js/min/all-min.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
</body>
</html>
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
   var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulputil = require('gulp-util');
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var path = require('path');
//var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var reneme =  require('gulp-rename');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('default', function(){

});

gulp.task('index', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src(['assets/js/min/*.js', 'assets/css/min/*.css'], {read: false});

    return target.pipe(inject(sources))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all-min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/min'));
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/css/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('all-min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/min'));
});
```

[image]

**Thanks for any help**

Comment: When you actually go to `/assets/css/min/` on your filesystem, do you see `all-min.css`?

Comment: yes.. all-min-css. Do you know any solutions to fix this?Thanks

Comment: So instead of creating a file called `all-min.css` it creates a file just called `all-min-css` when you run `gulp css`?

Comment: Yes gulp  create all-min.css store it in <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/assets /css/min / all-min.css">

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused: if it's creating `all-min.css` then it's a problem with your server or gulp output configuration. If it's creating `all-min-css` then it's a problem with your gulpfile.

Comment: i think assets without / href="assets/" should be work

Comment: That shouldn't really matter. Try this, to check if your server is the issue: create a new file called `test.css` manually within `/assets/css/min/` and then try to browse to `localhost/assets/css/min/test.css` and see if it returns the file you created.

Comment: I updated the gulpfile.js

Comment: When I open the source code and click on the css link redirects me to localhost / asset / css / min / all-min.css /  | but My application looks like this  localhost/app/assets/css/min/all-min.css... I do not understand where is the problem